# Attempting to create a binary search square root calculator, receiving 0 as a result every time

Tags: java, search, binary, square-root

I'm extremely new to Java, and in my first class for it ever currently. I've been tasked with creating a binary search square root calculator. I believe my methods and syntax are mostly correct, though for some reason I am receiving 0 as a result no matter what number I input in my program. Can anyone tell me what is going wrong in my calculation method?

```
public static double calculation(double userInput, double lowerBound, double upperBound, double midPoint) {
  // Workaround method to calculate the square root of a double integer value, with the use of two bounds getting infintely closer to a fixed point (the square root).
  midPoint = (lowerBound + upperBound) / 2;
  upperBound = userInput;
  while(midPoint*midPoint - userInput > 0.001 || midPoint*midPoint - userInput < -0.001)
  {
    if (midPoint*midPoint > userInput)
    {
      lowerBound = midPoint;
    }
    else if (midPoint*midPoint < userInput)
    {
      upperBound = midPoint;
    }
  }
  midPoint = (lowerBound + upperBound) / 2;
  return midPoint;
}
```

This is my first real post to this website, I apologize if my formatting was incorrect in any way. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I can provide more lines of code if need be, though Im assuming the solution should be doable with just this section. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When execution enters the `while` loop, it will never exit, because `midPoint` never changes inside the loop body, and so the loop condition will be true, forever. I think you want to add this line as the last statement in the loop:

```
midPoint = (lowerBound + upperBound) / 2;
```

Another bug is that the loop condition doesn't really make sense.
I don't think the `midPoint` is meant to go within the range of `(-0.001, 0.001)`. I think what you meant is this:

```
while(midPoint*midPoint - userInput > 0.001 || midPoint*midPoint - userInput < -0.001)
```

With these two changes, your program should terminate and work as expected.

Comment: Hmmm, i've tried adjusting my code to reflect the responses in this thread, though i'm running into the same problem. There must be an issue in the overall code, not just this one method, i'll edit the op.

Comment: Hm, thanks for accepting... Does that mean you figured out the rest? (I sure hope so...)

Comment: (If you couldnt tell, im extremely new to this website, haha). Your response definitely figured out the issue in that method which was my original question. I've yet to figure out the overlying issue in my program though.

Comment: It would be better to roll back your question to its previous state, and to post a new question with the current text.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no reason to have the midpoint be passed as a parameter when it's calculated.  Remove it and have `midPoint` be a local variable.
2. You're comparing the midPoint squared to `0.001` and `-0.001`, instead of using those constants as adjustments to `userInput`.  This will cause the answer to be `0`.  Try this instead:

```
while(midPoint*midPoint > userInput + 0.001 || midPoint*midPoint < userInput - 0.001)
```

3. Your adjustments of the lower bound and upper bound are backwards.  Try this:

```
    if (midPoint*midPoint > userInput)
    {
        lowerBound = midPoint;
    }
    else if (midPoint*midPoint < userInput)
    {
        upperBound = midPoint;
    }
```

4. You must calculate your new `midPoint` once the lower bound or upper bound is adjusted.

```
    midPoint = (lowerBound + upperBound) / 2;
}
```